# Reduction of closed orbit lemma by Galois descent

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

I am reading a proof of the closed orbit lemma:

> If $G$ is a smooth $k$-group of finite type acting on a finite-type
>   $k$-scheme $X$, and $x$ is a $k$-point of $X$, then the orbit map of
>   $x$ $\alpha_x: G \to X$ sending $g$ to $gx$ has a locally closed set
>   theoretic image, and is smooth when given the reduced induced scheme
>   structure.

In the first step the author tries to reduce it to $k$ being separably closed, saying that this can be done by Galois descent. Can anyone expand on this point, or give me a reference on Galois descent on properties of morphisms?

Comment: I wrote a proof for the smoothness. Does the question also concerns with locally closedness ?